# How to change the Color of the DatePicker in Flutter Webview

Tags: flutter, webview, android-webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I have had this same issue as discussed in
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100067

I was able to get the flutter Webview.
But I need to change the color from Aqua to Blue as shown in the plus button in bottom Navigation bar. Please Help. [image]

Comment: Please try to add your Datepicker code and + button color

Comment: This datepicker is opening in webview. 
I have not used showDatePicker Method. Refer to - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100067

Answer (score 1):

Refer the [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100067) and [configuration](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#enabling-material-components)

1. Open the `build.gradle` file for your application.
2. Make sure that the repositories section includes Google's Maven Repository google(). For example:

   ```
     allprojects {
      repositories { 
      google() 
      centre() 
     }
   }
   ```
3. 

Add the library to the dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7'
    // ...
  }
```

4. Set the light theme in /android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:
   content_copy
   change

to

```
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

5. Set the dark theme in /android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml
   content_copy
   change

to

```
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, refer [showDatePicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html)

```
builder: (context, child) {
        return Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Colors.indigo,//add your + button color here
             ),
            textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                foregroundColor: Colors.indigo, // button text color
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
```

Full Code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Colors.indigo,
             ),
            textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                foregroundColor: Colors.indigo, // button text color
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Datepicker'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("${selectedDate.toLocal()}".split(' ')[0]),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _selectDate(context),
              child: Text('Select date'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: I am not using this showDatePicker()
Instead I am opening this from WebView. 
please refer to the link I have given in my question. @Ravindra